# Double posting across StackOverflow Network

Tags: discussion, migration, etiquette

I originally meant to post my question to the Sharepoint section, but did so under StackOverflow home.  Is it frowned upon to ask the question again under the SharePoint section?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag your post for moderator attention, and state you want it moved to the Sharepoint site:

[image: Flag for mod attention]

Whatever you do, don't just post it on the Sharepoint site while there is still as chance it could be migrated for you. Note that if the migration was declined, it usually is because the Sharepoint moderators did not want it migrated there due to question quality or it being off-topic for their site. The moderators can clarify that for you.

Comment: So just add a comment requesting a move?

Comment: No, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @Sean: I've added an illustative image for you.

Comment: Sorry mate.  Took me a second. Thanks very much.